# Can't use IServiceCollection even with NuGet package

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I'm trying to add dependency injection to my .NET 4.7.2 MVC application. I've created a Startup file like so:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Startup
{
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
   {

   }

   public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {

   }
}
```

Which is just empty, I've added `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` from NuGet package manager but for some reason I get this error -

> The type or namespace name 'IServiceCollection' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Does anyone know what I'm missing? I've followed the Microsoft website but still stuck.

Comment: And how are you intending to integrate this into ASP.NET MVC? Adding a `Startup` class does not magically add DI capabilities to MVC. You likely need to implement either an `IDependencyResolver` or `IControllerFactory` implementation and auto-register your MVC controllers as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicecollection), this interface lives in assembly `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll`.

I'm guessing you are installing `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll`, and not the Abstractions assembly.

The docs also complain when I try to switch the framework version to 4.7.2, so maybe this interface does not exist for that version of the framework.

> The requested page is not available for .NET Framework 4.7.2. You have
> been redirected to the newest product version this page is available
> for.

Comment: I don't understand because I can use `ServiceCollection()` but not `IServiceCollection`

Comment: @KTOV `ServiceCollection` is the implementation, `IServiceCollection` is the abstraction. They're in different packages. You only have the former installed.